# Typescript error - "type is declared but never used" in .ts. When it was used in interface

Tags: typescript

Why typescript give me error "'HttpRequest' is declared but never used." when HttpRequest was used in interface? How to fix this?

```
import fp from 'fastify-plugin'
import fastify from 'fastify'
import { IncomingMessage } from 'http'
import { Http2ServerRequest } from 'http2'

//'HttpRequest' is declared but never used.
type HttpRequest = IncomingMessage | Http2ServerRequest

declare module 'fastify' {
  interface FastifyRequest<
    HttpRequest,
    Query = fastify.DefaultQuery,
    Params = fastify.DefaultParams,
    Headers = fastify.DefaultHeaders,
    Body = any
  > {
    user: string
  }
}

function plugin(fastify, options, next) {
  fastify.decorateRequest('user', 'userData')
  next()
}

export const reqDecorator = fp(plugin)
```

Here is the FastifyRequest interface:

```
interface FastifyRequest<HttpRequest = IncomingMessage, Query = fastify.DefaultQuery, Params = fastify.DefaultParams, Headers = fastify.DefaultHeaders, Body = any>
```

Comment: is this `.ts` file or `.d.ts` file?

Comment: it's .ts file.......

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined name for the type,

```
declare module 'fastify' {
  interface FastifyRequest<
    httpRequest = HttpRequest,
```

As `IncomingMessage` is used as type, again you need to give name for the type for `FastifyRequest` interface,

```
export interface FastifyRequest<httprequest = IncomingMessage, // added this
Query = fastify.DefaultQuery,
Params = fastify.DefaultParams,
Headers = fastify.DefaultHeaders,
Body = any> {
  // interface fields and methods
}
```

Comment: Added FastifyRequest interface. If i do like HttpRequest = HttpRequest i've get "All declarations of 'FastifyRequest' must have identical type parameters"

Comment: but FastifyRequest is part of fastify framework, i can't modify it and export ;/ Or i just don't understand something

Comment: httprequest = IncomingMessage gives the same error: "All declarations of 'FastifyRequest' must have identical type parameters"